# ASP.NET Web Application and AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a web application that I build and publish it using “**Publish Web Site**” feature in Visual Studio 2012. The settings for precompile web site is as shown in the picture

[image: settings for precompile web site]

Now I want to give the final assembly a file version which I’ve done that using `AssemblyInfo.cs` according to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228042.aspx)

[image: project structure]

The problem is that although I set the file version in the `AssemblyInfo.cs`, the output assembly version is always **1.0.0.0**.

In fact, the compiler creates its own `AssemblyInfo.cs` somewhere else that is shown in picture and builds it and then finally merges it with application assembly.

[image]

I don’t know how to change this behavior of “Publish Web Site” feature the way that it copy the provided AssemblyInfo.cs and not create its own.

Any help is appreciated

**UPDATE:**

the `web.config` is set as said here ([How to: Create Versioned Assemblies for Precompiled Web Site Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228042.aspx))

[image]

I have set the `compilerOptions` in `web.config` as well as `web.debug.config` with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `AssemblyInfo.cs` or your `Web.config` files look like because you haven't supplied them, but I am thinking that you haven't added the code to the `Web.config` file like it says to do in the link that you supplied.

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System,
      Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="1" 
      compilerOptions="path\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

you probably didn't add it to the `Web.Debug.config` file, that is probably why it isn't working while you are debugging.